# Tomcat websocket задать размер буфера для передачи blob

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

при передачи по ws больших объёмов на выскакивает такое

**No async message support and buffer too small. Buffer size: [8,192], Message size: [132,420]**

где следует указать размер буфера чтоб не было такой ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

как вариант можно сделать так

```
 @OnOpen
    public void OnOpen(EndpointConfig endpointConfig, Session userSession) {
        userSession.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(9000000);
     }
```